# how to download office 365 mail attachment file using laravel/PHP

Tags: laravel-5, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft graph API for fetching office 365 mails. I got all the emails from the API call but I don't know how to save an attachment from the message object. How do I save `contentBytes` to file?

```
Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message Object
(
  [_propDict:protected] => Array
  (
    [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metada
    [@odata.type] => #microsoft.graph.fileAttachment
    [@odata.mediaContentType] => application/pdf
    [id] => AAMkADM4MDYwMDkxLWRmN2UtNDJmMC04NDEwLTljZmQ2N2I4Zjc5NABGAAAAAAAix7kDZj2fRq
    [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2016-04-18T09:44:53Z
    [name] => 1 ) Muhammad Abdullah New.pdf
    [contentType] => application/pdf
    [size] => 104767
    isInline] =>
    [contentId] => C#$F3@eurprd06.prod.outlook.com
    [contentLocation] => 
    [contentBytes] => JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNyuFJFtfTffYSTIgCjUwNSAwIG9iag08PC9MaW
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got a solution.We get base64_encoded contentBytes from the Graph API, we need to convert contentBytes to base64_decode format.so you have to write base64_decoded content to a file.

```
$content=base64_decode($attachment_data->getcontentBytes(),true);
file_put_contents(public_path(). "/sample/".$attachment_data->getname(),$content);
// download code
```